# Antlr4: Parsing JSP tag with nested tag in attribute value

Tags: antlr4

I need to parse a few JSP files. There is a special rule in JSP that is different from normal HTML:

The attribute value (quoted string) can contain an inline tag, such as the following cases are valid:

1. `<a value="<b v="123"/>"></a>` nested tags
2. `<a value="List<String>"></a>` normal attribute Value: `List<String>`
3. `<a value="<"></a>` normal attribute value: `<`

I tried to use the lexer mode, which can handle Case 1, but failed to handle the Case 2 & 3.

Is it possible to use Antrl4 to parse such text?

**UPDATE**

A simplified version of my lexer:

```
lexer grammar JSPLexer;

@members{
    private int tagNestLevel;
}

TAG_OPEN            :   '<' { tagNestLevel = 0; }   -> pushMode(TAG_MODE);
TAG_CLOSE_SLASH     :   '</'                        -> pushMode(TAG_MODE);

mode TAG_MODE;

TAG_SLASH_CLOSE     :   '/>'                        -> popMode;
TAG_NEST_OPEN       :   '<' { tagNestlevel++; }     -> type(TAG_OPEN), pushMode(TAG_MODE)
TAG_CLOSE           :   '>' { tagNestLevel == 0 }?  -> popMode;
EQ                  :   '=';
NAME                :   [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_.:-]*;
DOUBLE_QUOTE_OPEN   :   '"'                         -> pushMode(DOUBLE_STRING_MODE);
WS_TAG              :   [ \t\r\n]+                  -> channel(HIDDEN)

mode DOUBLE_STRING_MODE;

DOUBLE_QUOTE_CLOSE  :   '"'                         -> popMode;
DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRINGTAG_CLOSE_SLASH : '</'           -> type(TAG_CLOSE_SLASH), pushMode    (TAG_MODE);
DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING_TAG_OPEN :  '<' { tagNestLevel = 0; } ->type(TAG_OPEN), pushMode    (TAG_MODE);
DOUBLE_QUOTE_TEXT   :   ~["<]+;
```

Comment: In general, yes. Typically, the solution involves using recursive modes. Show what you have working so far for more detailed help.

Comment: @GRosenberg Yes, I used recursive mode. But the problem is that when I come across a `<` in strings, I can't be sure whether it is a TAG start or belongs to a normal attribute value. For now when I have encountered `<` then I `pushMode( TAG)`, but for the normal attribute value, the following tokens parsed out are all wrong.

Comment: Insufficient information to help further.

Comment: @GRosenberg see update please.